# Ubuntu Desktop on Rpi 4 8GB no display after boot

Tags: boot, display, hdmi, raspberrypi, 21.10

So I used the regular raspberry-pi-imager tool for windows and flashed the "Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 (RPi 4/400)" on my brand new raspberry pi 4 8GB ram model.

During the boot, the regular RGB spectrum is shown and then I'm presented with the loading screen with the ubuntu logo in the middle of the screen and the spinner below that and the "ubuntu" text below the spinner.

After a while the screen goes blank and nothing ever pops up, my monitor goes to standby mode.

I've tried the `hdmi_safe=1` on the config file and no change.

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting the hdmi plug still no output on my monitor.

To make sure my RPi4 is not damaged, I installed the Raspberry Pi OS and that worked as expected.

Then, I flashed it with the EEPROM bootloader and it successfully worked.

I was using a 32GB microSD card so I did it again with a 16GB one yet the same issue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you managed to get any progress on this?